# parametrize server and database name in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to paramterize sql server name and database name so that when its changed I dont have to change everything but only 1 line ?

thanks for any help

Comment: In what context? Do you mean in TSQL Scripts, or in C# application code or in stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear - but I'm interpreting as this: you would like to do something like:

```
SELECT (list of fields) 
FROM @database.dbo.@tablename
WHERE (clause)
```

or something - right?

No, you cannot do this - at least not in standard SQL  - you'd have to use dynamic SQL (string together your SQL command as a variable, and then execute that).

If you think about going there - you **must** read Erland Sommarskog's excellent [The Curse and Blessings of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) and think again if you really want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If they are scripts to be run in SSMS or from the command line, just use [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) mode, you can use substitutions for just about anything.